# Read excel file in Java with NetBeans

Tags: java

I need to read an excel file. I wrote this code but it has an error.

Here is my code:

```
package javaapplication9;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

    //File fileName = new File("C://sadegh//test.xlsx");
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C://sadegh//test.xlsx");

    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
    if (cell == null)
        cell = row.createCell(3);
    System.out.println(cell.toString());


    }catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e5){
            //e5.notify();
            }catch (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException e3) {

                e3.printStackTrace();

            }
catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();

            }

    }

}
```

This is the error as shown in the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<clinit>(Package.java:63)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:62)
        at javaapplication9.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

What are the causes of the error?

Here are my libs imported. I'm using:

```
xbean.jar
xbean_xpath.jar
xmlbeans-qname.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
poi_ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-3.8-20120326.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the log4 jar as lib in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache POI requires Log4J 1.2.13

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

You can download it here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.13/log4j-1.2.13.jar